How to replace the inline button after entering text in a telegram bot
I use the telebot library, but I have an error, I need to enter text so that after clicking the button text changes
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, key)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start_0(message):

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    switch1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вход', callback_data='btn1')
    markup.add(switch1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "меню:", reply_markup=markup)

def wallet(message):

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    switch_back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='\U000021A9 Назад', callback_data='back21')
    markup.add(switch_back)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = message.id,text='Введите адрес своего кошелька', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, key)

def key(message):

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    switch_back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='\U000021A9 Назад', callback_data='back22')
    markup.add(switch_back)
    messages = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id,text='Вы ввели неверный адрес кошелька', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data)

def buttons(call):

    if call.data == 'btn1':
        wallet(call.message)


